# setContentView problem

Tags: android

I am beginner in android so some beginer problems is occured. I create second activiy and second layout xml file named  getNearest.xml.  The code section to show this file is

```
  setContentView(R.layout.getNearest)
```

But eclipse cannot be find getNearest. It only shows .main. So what is the problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build at least once to have the R.layout values updated when you create a new layout.  Also make sure you saved the layout file and that it exists under the res\layout folder.